# Send email reminder in Google sheets as per the cell value or the date

Tags: google-apps-script

Sheet link : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BYl_xTnhOMbBueb0ttdIeNIbrphmyk2JmywmHsT-NWs/edit#gid=0

Need to send an email, if column 7 is equal to current date or if the column 8 is equal to the word email. It should send all the information in that particular row.

Comment: And your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you do this with Zapier it will work.

https://zapier.com/zapbook/google-sheets/

You create a trigger for a new line, and create filter in the flow/process, for the column 8, (And for column 7, if that is really necessary, dont looks that way) depending on the data in the row.

[Part of the flow in Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDsZA.png)